# Bootstrap DataTables1.10 currency sorting not working

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, sorting, datatable

Sample of how one row of currency value is formatted prior to passing to table.

```
 var client = new Client();
 //get data from JSON item,
 //format data as $##,##.##, add to row object
 client.amount = item.fAmt.formatMoney(2, "$", ",", ".");
 results in client.amount = "$500,000.000" etc;

 //add object to dataset
 dataSet[loop]=client;
```

datatable snippet

```
.dataTable({    
  "data": dataSet,
  "columns": [
    {"title": "Amount", className:"text-center", data:"amount"},
    ..
  ]
});
```

The data displays in the column but it doesn't sort. It seems like the data is being treated as text when sorting and not currency. I read that version 1.10 automatically deals with currency.

Comment: How does the currencies look like? Like $500,000.000??

Comment: should have entered $500,000.00

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution: under certain circumstances some values passed to the table were not formatted as currency ($0,000.00) and this caused all values for this column to be treated as String.